# Task switcher not showing terminal windows

Tags: 11.10, shortcut-keys, application-switcher

Upgraded to 11.10 this morning.

Terminal windows stopped showing in the <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> switcher.

What's the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: Is the problem that only *one* of the terminals is showing up? Do any show up?

Comment: I was experiencing the same problem and tried to fix it by gconf as explained above, but in my gconf there was not any folders named "mutter"... HOWEVER, the problem unexpectedly DISAPPEARED when the system was RESTARTED...

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, but disappeared now (I think after restart)
As an alternative you can use <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>up_arrow</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

Open CCSM (CompizConfig Settings Manager) go to **Ubuntu Unity Plugin > Switcher**

Untick *Bias alt-tab to prefer window on the current viewport*

Comment: This issue with Terminator resurfaced in 16.04 and the above solved it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here. I think it started after I added terminal to launcher. After experimenting with `gconf-editor`, I found a solution:

1. Open `gconf-editor`.
2. In `gconf-editor` goto: apps ➤ mutter ➤ general.
3. Tick the key named `live_hidden_windows`.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, but with chromium-browser and [keepassx](https://askubuntu.com/questions/76627/keepassx-0-4-3-on-11-10-unity-not-visible-in-task-switcher-alt-tab).

Ugly but effective: from a terminal window, start gnome-panel. The minimized window shows up in the panel, click to un-minimize, then kill the gnome-panel.