# KeePassX 0.4.3 on 11.10 (Unity) not visible in task switcher (Alt-Tab)

Tags: 11.10, unity

**Update:** Problem solved.  I've rebooted, and now it just works.  I cannot reproduce the problem anymore myself.

(Reported as https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/keepassx/+bug/887115)

I run KeePassX, then switch to another application. Now neither is the KeePassX window accessible by using Alt-Tab / task switcher, nor in the left-hand launcher icons. I have to manually move the other application windows out of the way to get back to the KeePassX window. I don't dare minimize it ...

I have the KeePassX icon added to the launcher, but it has no indicator for the open application window, and when I click it again, it just opens another KeePassX instance.

I would expect the KeePassX window(s) to be visible in the launcher and task switcher just like any other application windows.

Any idea what could be the problem?

**Workarounds:** Right-click on the KeePassX window title bar, and choose "Always On Top". Keeps the window in the foreground and I don't loose it. Or: Alt-Shift-Up also exposes the KeePassX window. (Found the latter on [Task switcher not showing terminal windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66528/task-switcher-not-showing-terminal-windows/67936#67936))

Comment: KeePassX is Qt-based, KeePass is the .Net thing.  Anyway, never mind my question, as I just restarted my system and the problem just disappeared :/

Comment: I tried, but didn't have the reputation yet for doing it right away. But thanks for your answers here, might be helpful for other occasions.